# Unable to send .NET transaction to DB2 server in window 2003

Tags: .net, transactions, db2

I am working on a project which need to use .NET Transaction with DB2 server on window server 2003.

The point is when I tried to send the transaction from Vista platform to DB2 server, it show some error like this:

```
SQL0998N  Error occurred during transaction or heuristic processing.  Reason Code = "16". Subcode = "2-80004005"
```

The google's result told me about DTC is not enabled, but I enable this function already. This problem doesn't found on XP Service Pack 3. but we have to work on this in Vista.

Could you help me eliminate this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly enable DTC on the Windows Server 2003 machine?

A good walkthrough can be found here: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/how-to-configure-dtc-on-windows-2003/